# Black flashes on Minecraft

Tags: 14.04, java, minecraft, nvidia-geforce

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop and wanted to install minecraft. It started perfectly fine (No black screens, no crashes) but after a few seconds, my whole screen goes black for 1 second, it only affect the screen where the game is running and does not stop my inputs (I can still move and do stuff but I don't see it). After it happens for the first time, the top of my screen starts to flicker and the black flashes become more and more frequent. It doesn't happen when I'm not moving.

I tried updating java and the drivers for my graphic card but it didn't change anything.

My graphics card is a Nvidia Geforce GTX 950M

I didn't have this problem when my computer was still on windows and it never happened on my desktop (also on ubuntu 14.04).

If you need any precisions on the nature of the problem or about my config, please ask.

Thanks

Comment: Does reducing the graphics settings reduce the issue?

Comment: No, I tried with the lowest settings possible, no difference

Comment: Do you have the latest version of OpenGL installed?

Comment: See if this helps you (it's for 16.04, but it may work): http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics/760935#760935

Comment: Yes, I have the latest OpenGl. Zacharee's solution seems to work, although I don't really understand why :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the graphics card drivers, reinstall it by following this thread :[Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics/760935#760935) (It's for 16.04 but works for 14.04)
For the install step, make sure you install the correct version of the driver (you can check which one you need for your GPU on Nvidia's website)